Primes calculating program throws segmentation fault when i > 500k
I am creating a C program to calculate the primes from 2 to maxCheck. It's pretty simple, just goes up in a for loop from 2 to maxCheck and checks whether i is prime for each cycle. If the number is found to be prime, I save it in an array int previousPrimes[maxCheck] to be used to calculate later primes. To test whether a number is a prime or not, the program runs a for loop running from 0 to currentNumPrimes. For each cycle, I test whether num % previousPrimes[i] == 0 and if it does, it is not a prime. If num passes all the checks, it is declared prime, is added to previousPrimes, and currentNumPrimes is incremented.
I know this much works. The problem is occurs when maxCheck is higher than roughly 500,000. Any higher than this and the program either returns with a Segmentation fault or it doesn't return anything. I have tried adding debug prints in main to see where it fails, but it doesn't help. I don't think that I am going >= INT_MAX, but I could be...
To be clear, I purposely do not initialise previousPrimes. I realise that this is good practice, but I didn't see a difference one way or the other (I tried both).
Here is main and the checkForPrime function:
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    int previousPrimes[maxCheck];

    for (int i = 2; i < (maxCheck + 1); i++) {
        if (checkForPrime(i, previousPrimes)) {
            previousPrimes[currentNumPrimes] = i;
            currentNumPrimes++;
            printf("%s%d Is Prime\n", green, i);
        } else {
            printf("%s%d Is Not Prime\n", cyan, i);
        }            
    }
    printf("\n%s%f percent of numbers checked were prime", normal, ((double)currentNumPrimes / (double)maxCheck * 100));
}

And the checkForPrime code:
int checkForPrime(int num, int previousPrimes[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < currentNumPrimes; i++) {
        if (num % previousPrimes[i] == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}


Idea: int previousPrimes[macCheck]; --> static unsigned previousPrimes[maxCheck];  (unsigned, zero initialization, avoid using stack space.)

I guess the duplicate I linked is C++ rather than C, but the idea still applies.  I seem to recall there was a C-specific canonical question somewhere, but I can't find it now.

Tip: to speed things up: Do not test against all known primes.  Only up while the quotient is >=  divisor.

Alright sorry. I actually looked at it but saw it was in C++ so didn't think it applied.

@NateEldredge - funny how the "Related questions" never are...

You should investigate segmented sieves for calculating primes.

Where is currentNumPrimes set?

@Wiimm It is a global variable. Set above checkForPrime.
